# WYSIWYG Editor in .NET

Tags: .net, winforms

I need a small WYSIWYG control in my application. The internal representation is some kind of xml, but I couldn't find anything in the internet concerning wysiwyg which appart from html or rtf editors.

For example when the internal representation is something like

```
"some text <ask pivot="x">name</ask> some text"
```

I want the user to see and edit

```
"some text some other text some text"
```

("other text" should be colorized and it should not be possible to edit single characters of it)

I could do the representation with a RichTextBox but it is afaik not possible to translate rtf into my format as pivot="x" has no impact on the visual appearance of "other text" but should be remembered anyway. Even if I would use a workarround, I would also need to do some hacking to make "other text" not editable, so it would be very messy and possibly to slow.

What's the best way to do this in .NET?

edit:
The application creates some kind of a template. There are several tags like  or  in the resulting text which will be replaced by another application. I want the user to edit these templates but not have to worry about the xml(they don't know xml), so instead of the xml tags I want the user to see an example replacement of them.
Instead of

```
I like <ask pivot="simple">fruit</ask>s
```

The user should see (and edit)

```
I like apples
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise on your description of what you want? Maybe a little schema or something like that could help, because honestly, I didn't understand anything.

Comment: added some clarification

Answer (score 0):

This is very big workaround but I think it would work. Use webbrowser control, in which put TinyMCE or some other WYSIWYG editor. I know it is naive and comparable to killing flies with a shotgun, may be it will do the job. Please let me know if you decide to do make it that way.

Cheers ]:>